# What is the atmospheric percentage of oxygen produced by trees and phytoplankton every year?

Tags: atmosphere, atmosphere-modelling, atmospheric-chemistry, greenhouse-gases, oxygen

I know that every year carbon sinks remove ~20Gt of CO<sub>2</sub> (about half of our emissions), and release a comparable amount of O<sub>2</sub> , But I want to know how much O<sub>2</sub>  the carbon sinks produce annually percentage wise (of the total atmosphere composition) considering the total annual carbon flux of ~800 Gt of CO<sub>2</sub> .